# Excel transpose array into single column

Tags: arrays, excel, transpose

I am trying to transpose the following array into a single column. Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking Power Query is your friend here.

Comment: Yes `Power Query` should be the right option here as mentioned by @Skin

Comment: There is nothing much to do, just load the data into `PQ` --> Select all the columns and unpivot and sort with the value column as `Ascending Order` and then import the same into excel